# HATBM association, how can I get pairs of associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Given following models and association:
[image: association model]
<sub>(source: [rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/has_many_through.png))</sub>

How can I get an array of pairs (`physician_name`, `patient_name`) that are appointed for certain day (`appointment_date`)? You can assume that one patient will never go to the same physician twice. Never.

I already tried things like:
        `@appointments = Appointment.where(appointment_date: params[:date])` 
but I have no idea what to do further. Should I iterate through this array and get every pair like this below?

```
@appointments.each do |appointment|
@physician = Physicians.where(id: :appointment.physician_id)
@patient = Patients.where(id: :appointment_patient_id)
```

I believe there's much easier way.

I'm using Rails 4.2.5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is approximately this:

```
Appointment.includes([:physician, :patient]).where(:date => appointment_date).map{|a| [a.physician.name, a.patient.name]}
```

Since only the Physician and Patient models have the names, they'll need to be loaded in the query (ok, you could avoid it by doing some fancy SQL trickery, but this is database-agnostic, which is convenient). Hence `includes`, which eager-loads associated models.

Then use `.where` to return only the appointments on the day you want (may be more complex if you're actually setting times in those DateTime values).

And finally, iterate over the list and return an Array of Arrays (Ruby not having Tuples) containing the names.